# How can I get the current Active Solution Platform name for use in a Visual Studio add-in? (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, add-in

I am creating a Visual studio add-in writing in C# allowing users to send their code to a remote PC for parsing. The process will differ depending on what Active Solution Platform is being used.

I would like the add-in to be able to obtain the current Active Solution Platform so the users code can be processed correctly.

I tried the following:

```
try    
{
SolutionBuild builder = applicationObject.Solution.SolutionBuild;
SolutionConfiguration2 config;
config = (SolutionConfiguration2)builder.SolutionConfigurations.Item(1);
MessageBox.Show("The platform name of 
the solution configuration is: " + config.PlatformName);
}
catch(SystemException ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

However this always returns the first Platform in the list, not the current platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the configuration name and platform name for the active project.

```
object[] openProjects = (object[])applicationObject.ActiveSolutionProjects;
Project activeProject = (Project)openProjects[0];
string configurationName = activeProject.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration.ConfigurationName;
string platformName = activeProject.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration.PlatformName;
```

Comment: Thanks this helps, however I now see it can be improved further so as to give the current project, not just the first in the list in the following way:    string configurationName = applicationObject.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration.ConfigurationName;

Comment: this gets the platform for the current project, which isn't always the same as the solution platform

Answer (score 4):

To get the active solution config and platform use this

```
string active_config = (string)addin_inst.DTE.Solution.Properties.Item("ActiveConfig").Value;
```

This will get a string of the form "Debug|Win32". The platform will be after the '|'